# Keeping duplicate files in a github repository

Tags: github

I am writing a library that should be accessible to `R`, `python`, `matlab` and `C` users. The code that is doing the hard work is written in `C` and I have written wrappers for the other languages. Let's call that file `worker.c`.

`R` and `python` packages/modules have a directory structure that requires that all files associated with the package/module are contained in one directory. Hence, I need to have a copy of `worker.c` in the `R` and `python` directories of the `git` repository but it feels wrong to have duplicate files in one repository.

Is there any way of automatically syncing them? Would `symlinks` work? If so, are they suitable for Windows users?